# fileNotfound exception of my properties file

Tags: properties, spring-mvc

i am trying to use a custom .properties file i created to host some properties about a SQL database but the issue is that my spring app cant find it.

i get the following error

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/jdbc.properties]

i have tried to put this file in the root of my project and also inside the root of the WEB-INF folder and still no joy.

my properties configurer bean looks like this:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>jdbc.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: What do you mean "the root of my project"?

Comment: I was going to ask the same question. :]  Jonney, try putting jdbc.properties in the root of your classpath, rather than the root of your project.  This is usually src/java/main/, or possibly src/ if you're not using Maven.

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that the `jdbc.properties` file should go in the root of the WAR, i.e. alongside the `WEB-INF` directory, not inside it.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you try classpath*:jdbc.propertie or classpath:jdbc.properties?

Comment: ok i will try that. where does the properties folder suppose to go?

Comment: `classpath:something.properties` doesn't work while `classpath*:something.properties` does. What does the latter mean?

Answer (score 1):

It could be one of 2 things:

(1) The propertyPlaceholder cant find the file because it is nested in a folder. That's okay because you can add your resources using the `classpath:` directive. Here is an example:

```
<bean id="propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    <property name="propertiesArray">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

(2) If you are using Maven, you are probably not including that file in your classpath using the maven build resources element.

```
      <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/filtered-resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Perhaps you are only including xml files, or you are excluding certain file paths :)